# ruby regex find and replace

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following output:
`time = 15:40:32.81`

And I want to eliminate `:` and the `.` so that it looks like this:
`15403281`

I tried doing a

```
time.gsub(/\:\s/,'')
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
"15:40:32.81".gsub(/:|\./, "")
```

Answer (score 6):

```
time = '15:40:32.81'
numeric_time = time.gsub(/[^0-9]+/, '')
# numeric_time will be 15403281
```

`[^0-9]` specifies a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) containing any character which is not a digit (`^` at the beginning of a class negates it), which will then be replaced by an empty string (or, in other words, removed).

(Updated to replace `\d` with `0-9` for clarity, though they are equivalent).

Comment: The + isn't necessary; time.gsub(/[^\d]/,"") works just as well.

Comment: @todb true, but it'll cause a bigger chunk of the string to be replaced at once if multiple non-numeric characters appear in a row.

Comment: On such a short string, neither variation matters a whole lot. :) I also never use [^\d]. [^0-9] is only one more character and I think it lends reading clarity. I have no idea if there's a performance difference between the two.

Comment: @todb As far as I know, if there is any difference it would be negligible. `\D` could have been used instead of the character class, for that matter.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be fancy and use an actual time object...

```
time = Time.now
time.strftime("%H%M%S") + time.usec.to_s[0,2]
# returns "15151788"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
time.delete ':.'
```

But it'll edit your variable. If you don't want it:

```
time.dup.delete ':.'
```

Comment: Actually `delete!` would perform the delete in place. Then again this answer is old, so who knows what things where like in 2010.